# Why was it necessary for Sheidim to be on the Teivah?

Tags: parashat-noach, sheidim-demons

Noach, Perek 6
[רש"י: (יט) ומכל החי – אפילו [ה] שדים:

From Rashi, we learn that demons ('sheidim') were on the teivah of Noach as well as animals and humans.

Why was this necessary? If they're spirits without flesh (as Sifsei Chachamim elaborates there), how could the Mabul harm them? Furthermore, why would we want them to be saved?

Comment: https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=78919&sid=b23cf6377a830b94c13f6d5ff36692af

Comment: I heard a beautiful interpretation once that shedim could really be a metaphor for bacteria or germs. So like when the Gemara says “if a person knew how many shedim were around him always he’d live in constant fear”, that could mean if you knew all the germs around you you’d be so paranoid all the time. This is just one example but with most other shedim teachings that I’ve come across this interpretation makes sense. So here, maybe it means certain diseases or germs were carried along the ark?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's what Sifsei Chachamim means. Rashi is based off the gemara in Chagiga 16a which states shades are similar to angels in three ways and to humans in three ways.

> ששה דברים נאמרו בשדים שלשה כמלאכי השרת ושלשה כבני אדם שלשה כמלאכי השרת יש להם כנפים כמלאכי השרת וטסים כמלאכי השרת ויודעין מה שעתיד לבא כמלאכי השרת יודעין סלקא דעתך אלא אימא שומעין מה שעתיד להיות שלשה כבני אדם אוכלין ושותין כבני אדם פרין ורבין כבני אדם ומתים כבני אדם

So they are not completely flesh, nor are they completely spiritual.
So, since they are somewhat flesh like, they would have died in the flood. But, to whatever degree they are not flesh like, they would not have been included in the general description of 'from all the flesh', and the Torah had to use the description 'from all that lives', to include the shades.

As to why save them, first answer why Hashem would why save any of the carnivores and destructive creatures (man included, see there 8:21), and apply that to shades.

Comment: Why did Hashem save destructive creatures? Is there a general answer to that that is the answer to the OP's question?

Comment: @RabbiKaii, probably the same reason He created them i.e. to fulfill His will etc. and therefore wants their existence to continue…

Comment: @שלום the answer to every question is to fulfill His will :) . Either way a write up of what the answer is would improve the answer